# Testing audio in browser using Mocha (needs user interaction)

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, web-audio-api

I have some Mocha tests running in the browser and that is all working great so far -- but I'm now trying to expand that to test some WebAudio. Unfortunately, when I run my test I get the following in my console:

```
The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
```

Which is certainly correct behavior from the browser but it keeps my test from continuing.

Is there a way to get around this? I was thinking of putting a button on the page and having the `mocha.run();` command behind the click handler.

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of your code? I don't see a problem with clicking on any random element on the page (I don't think it needs to be a button), then running the audio--that's essentially what the user is doing, so it seems sufficiently elegant to me.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you mentioned is the one logged in Chrome which is why I guess you are using Chrome for testing. You can set the `--autoplay-policy` flag to change the default behavior in Chrome.

```
--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required
```

This will allow an `AudioContext` to start without any user interaction.

Please take a look at the testing configuration of `standardized-audio-context` for a full example which uses Mocha and Karma to run the tests.

https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context/blob/master/config/karma/config-unit.js#L136